DNS error when I try to access my SquareSpace Domain
Currently, I am trying to host a simple website for my llc so that Apple can verify my developer account.  The domain is from Google Domains which was recently migrated to SquareSpace and the website is hosted on AWS using s3 and Route 53.  The direct s3 link from the policies section is running but when I try the domain name on my web browser I get the DNS error.
The website will occasionally be running fine but most of the time it is down.  I have more than quadruple checked my Route 53 settings and there should be no issue.  I have cleared everything in the DNS records on the SquareSpace end but so far I have no idea where the isue lies.
I use DNS checker to see if the DNS is working, and the DNS seems to only be working in around half the areas which is odd.
To connect the s3 bucket to the domain, I use the name servers given by AWS Route 53 and plug it into SquareSpace.
Please let me know if you need any more information, thanks.
I cleared everything in the DNS section of the SquareSpace domain and connected the name servers to AWS Route 53.
It has been around 3 days since this issue and the problem does not seem to be the DNS server lagging.

Create a distribution using cloudfront(edge-optimized). This might solve your issue.

Choose the domain, origin path and name respectively.
Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
WAF as per your wish

4.Cache Policy- disabled
and rest as default.
Give it a try and let me know.

I tried that before and it did not work.
I'm afraid the problem is with AWS Route 53, since the s3 bucket link and the cloudfront link both work but the issue arrises when I try to access it through a domain
